# Audio jack not detected, sound playing from both speaker's and headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Using Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Windows 10 dual boot.

Sound was working fine earlier today, then I went through a windows update ://. Headphones plugged into the audio jack are not recognized in `Sound`
 but sound is played through both the speakers and the headphones. I have tried

- reloading `alsa` and `pulseaudio`
- reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`

But it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Not saying this is the solution but sometimes after an update you have to cold boot a couple of times.

Comment: Cold boot like restarting?

Comment: Restarting or Rebooting is a warm boot. Shutdown and power off followed by power on is a cold boot.

Comment: Ah okay I see, thanks it looks as though that fixed it.

Comment: I posted an answer. Please accept it, OR write your own answer and accept it, OR delete your question. One of these three steps will reduce the number of unanswered questions here in **Ask Ubuntu**. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes a Windows Update will leave sound card in an unstable state. Rebooting into Ubuntu inherits that unstable state. By completely shutting down (power off) and cold booting (power on) the sound card is reinitialized.

There are other times when cold booting users have to go to Windows first to turn on sound cards and then reboot into Ubuntu in order for sound to work. This scenario is not ideal and a better fix / patch should be sought.